# Retrieve an array of strings in REST API instead of array of objects

Tags: angular, rest

I want to use an array of guidelines (this.guidelines) which I retrieve through an angular service to display all the unique guidelines in a Mongo Collection.

```
  getGuidelines() {
this.getRecommendationservice.getUniqueGuidelines();
this.guidelinesubscription = this.getRecommendationservice.getGuidelineUpdateListener()
.subscribe ((guidelines:any ) => {
  this.guidelines = guidelines
});
```

}

the service itself

```
  getUniqueGuidelines() {
    this.http.get<{message: string, guidelines: any}>('http://localhost:3000/api/uniqueguidelines')
    .pipe(map((data) => {
      return data.guidelines.map(guideline => {
        return {guideline: guideline
        };
      });
    }))
    .subscribe((transformedGuidelines) => {
      this.guidelines = transformedGuidelines;
      this.guidelinesUpdated.next([...this.guidelines]);
    });
  }

  getGuidelineUpdateListener() {
    return this.guidelinesUpdated.asObservable();
  }
```

I have troubling accessing the guidelines array. for instance if I try

```
alert(this.guidelines[0]);
```

I think it is an array of objects instead of an array of strings. Can anyone point me in the right direction how to retrieve the array of strings correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give the content of `data` ?
If data.guidelines is an array of strings, you should probably just return this in getUniqueGuidelines:

`return data.guidelines;`